# Import-CSV add data Export

Tags: powershell

I'm having a heck of a time trying to import a CSV and run a Invoke-WebRequest to get data to add to a new Column..

```
$username = "Username"
$password = cat C:\Password.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password 

$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\users\Desktop\ImportTest.csv

foreach($c in $csv){

        $link = "https://MyURlToCallforData"
        $uri= $link + $c.stuff

        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri  -Credential $cred -UseBasicParsing| ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Property lastIdReportTime 
}

Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Desktop\TestOutput.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

No i can import it fine, I make the call and i see the results on the ISE but I can't export to a CSV or append the current File.

I've tried all sorts of things, trying to add a new content trying to add a psObject and whatever I do i fail at..

Hoping someone can give me a hand here.

The CSV is basically like this.

```
Date,Description
Text1,text2 
text3,text4
```

and i want to export it like this

```
Date,Description,NewInfo
Text1,text2,new5
text3,text4,new6
```

Comment: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/adding-columns-to-an-existing-csv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions to that question.
Here's one:

```
$username = "Username"
$password = cat C:\Password.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password 

$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\users\username\Desktop\ImportTest.csv
$link = "https://MyURlToCallforData" 
foreach($c in $csv){

        $uri= $link + $c.stuff
        $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri  -Credential $cred -UseBasicParsing| ConvertFrom-Json
        $c | Add-Member -name "NewInfo" -MemberType NoteProperty -value $($result | Select-Object -ExpandProperty lastIdReportTime)
        $c | Add-Member -name "SecondField" -MemberType NoteProperty -value $($result | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SomeOtherField)

}

$csv | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\TestOutput.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Edit: I just realized there was an issue with your code: Export-Csv isn't exporting anything

Second edit: "-ExpandProperty" is probably mandatory to avoid some type mix-up mess.

And here's a second possible solution. Pick your favorite ;)

```
$username = "Username"
$password = cat C:\Password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password 

$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\users\username\Desktop\ImportTest.csv

$link = "https://MyURlToCallforData"
$csv = $csv | Select-Object -Property *,@{name="NewInfo";expression = {

    $uri= $link + $c.stuff
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri  -Credential $cred -UseBasicParsing| ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -expandProperty lastIdReportTime
}}

$csv | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\TestOutput.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I'll test these now.. The first one is literally what i had before but i think i had it formatted wrong :(..

Would you mind removing the users name on the path? Forgot i had left that in there.

Comment: Done, hadn't seen it either :p

Comment: Let me know if you have issue. Obviously I couldn't test the whole thing, so I only tested bits.

Comment: Ahhh the first one is a beauty and it works wonderfully!!
Second one took a while to run and gave me no output.. But i love the first one :)

Comment: yea it is strange, would adding multiple columns with data need to use the Invoke-webrequest each time? Or would it be as simple as creating multiple new properties where it is being done now?

Comment: How do you mean? You would like to create several properties based on the result of the same URI?

Comment: Pretty much, when i call the URI i have hundreds of fields i can grab.. I chose 1 to getting it working, ultimately i'll need about 5. So it would be 5 new properties.

Comment: Then you can just store the result of `Invoke-Webrequest` in a variable, without filtering the fields, and add properties based on that. I'll update the example.

Comment: ah! Thank you !  I sat here fighting with it and it's so obvious.. One day i'll hopefully figure it out  lol.  Thanks so much for all your help